# Load object with logic

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I believe that solution to my issue is relatively easy. I just don't see it.

I have an object:

```
function MyObject(){
  this.attr = "anything";
}

MyObject.prototype.doSomething = function(){
   // logic
}
```

I create the object using `new MyObject()`. I use it and when I want to quit what I do I simply store it into database (mongodb). In mongo it is stored in this way:

```
{ "attr" : "anything" }
```

When I load the object from database I only have the plain object literal without any logic. The methods are missing.  I can see why ;) but I don't know how to add the logic to the object literal again...

**Question**

How can I decorate the retrieved object with it's original logic again? So that it look like this again:

```
{       
  "attr" : "anything",
  "doSomething": doSomething()
}
```

- How to do it simply?
- Is there any other approach to this (except for storing the methods and all prototype hierarchy with it)?

Comment: json cannot hold functions. why not have your model (`MyObject`) as a module and on initialization you can pass it the json from the database to set its state?

Comment: @antoniskamamis Can you please provide some example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to create an object from the prototype without calling the constructor, and then use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to assign the properties from the object that you retrieved, to the newly created object:

```
var fullObject = Object.assign( Object.create( MyObject.prototype ), retrievedObject );
```

Example:

```js
function MyObject(){
  this.attr = "anything";
}

MyObject.prototype.doSomething = function(){
  document.body.innerHTML = this.attr;
}

// Plain object retrieved from database
var retrievedObject = {       
  "attr" : "foobar"
};

// Object with proper prototype and properties
var myObject = Object.assign( Object.create( MyObject.prototype ), retrievedObject );

myObject.doSomething();
```

Comment: his main concern is to store the whole constructor and its prototype to the db which cannot be done with just json

Comment: @antoniskamamis First of all that could definitely be done with JSON, anything can be stored in JSON, you just need a way to serialize it to a string and then unserialize it again. Second, that is clearly not his main concern, in fact he never mentioned wanting to store the functions in the db, and explicitly mentioned wanting to decorate the object after retrieving it from the db.

Comment: No, I don't want to store functions to db. If you change the app logic then you would get some deprecated code. I'm trying this solution.

Comment: @Paulpro It's working very well. Thank you! Are aware of some drawdowns or potential performance issues when comparing solution from @MichaelDibbets?

Comment: @zatziky You're welcome. I can't think of any drawbacks, except that if you try to use the same trick in client-side JS you should be aware that Object.create, and even more-so Object.assign are fairly new standards and don't have much support across different browsers. MichaelDibbets `load` function is logically equivalent (excluding the extra `timestamp` logic) and will work everywhere, but may be slightly less performant.

Comment: @Paulpro Hm, that's bad. I need it for angularjs. I guess I will add comment to this part of code...

Comment: yea, the object create and assign will use native code to do the logic, which will be a lot faster than the interpreted jit code my code will implement. But, on older browsers *eyes internet explorer suspiciously* it might cause some issues to use the `create` and `assign` code. There you could use my code as a fallback within conditional comments. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Well, I just tried in IE 11 and it's not working... Guess, I will revert @MichaelDibbets solution. :)

Comment: @zatziky Yeah, Object.assign isn't included yet even in IE 11, it's quite new. Some libraries (at least: jquery, lodash/underscore) have something like it usually called `extend`. There is a [Polyfill you can use for it, provided by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill), (there is also one for [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill)) that basically makes `Object.assign` work in browsers that don't have support for it yet.

Comment: @zatziky It will be slower to use that than Michael's answer in those browsers though, since the polyfill basically does the same looping he has in the answer along with some extra work.

Comment: @zatziky Oh angular does have a version of assign too (also called `extend`): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend (still slower than Michael's answer)

Comment: Thanks you both very much! @MichaelDibbets and Paulpro

Answer (score 4):

Make a load function to load all the properties of the object you get back into your own object.

You can access your objects property names as an associative array index.

so `myobj.attr` is the same as `myobj['attr']`.

This helps with dynamically inserting data into your object whilst keeping full control of the data(my personal favorite) :-)

You can add some extra checks to prevent surplus data or do some extra things whatever you want. For example modifying timestamps.

```
function MyObject(data){
  if(typeof data !== 'undefined') {
     this.load(data);
  }
  else {
      this.attr = "anything";
  }
}

MyObject.prototype.doSomething = function(){
   // logic
}
MyObject.prototype.load = function(data) {
   for(var key in data) {
      if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
        this[key] = data[key];
        // Just sample validation check. wahtever you want.
        if(key == 'timestamp') {
             if(this[key] < new Date().getTime()-4000) {
                  this[key] = new Date().getTime();
             }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. From watching the code it seems to work. I implemented the solution @Paulpro provided.

Answer (score 0):

An extension to @paulpro's answer which I had to modify a little this piece of code `Object.create( MyObject.prototype )`. As I was using an inherited object this way it didn't instantiate `private` members properly. I simply replaced `Object.create( MyObject.prototype )` with `new MyObject()`. That's it.

**UPDATE 5/3/2016**

The safest way is to use [lodash's assing](https://lodash.com/docs#assign).

```
var objectWithLogic = _.assign(new MyObject(), data);
```